# How would I ask for a persons Age, Sex, and Location (ASL) in Japanese?

Tags: meaning, words, word-requests, abbreviations

The abbreviation means age, sex and location, and is used frequently in English speaking chatsites during introductions. Is there a similar term used in Japanese chatsites?

Comment: Yes, the term you're looking for is "1996".

Comment: No such equivalent, but Japanese chatters who regularly visit English-speaking rooms know ASL of course. I used to chat at Alamak site 20+ yrs ago.

Comment: @istrasci that made me laugh hard. LOL!

Comment: what's the joke, I don't get it :(

Comment: I have never heard of ASL before haha, but I'm guessing the 1996 joke is referring to the year; i.e. anonymous chats and talk of ASL sounds like something really outdated, e.g. from 1996

Comment: @kuchitsu:  Its heyday of usage was in the mid- to late- 90s, when instant messengers and chat rooms such as AOL/AIM, ICQ, or MSN were widely used, and users didn't typically have public profiles to know who they were chatting with.

Answer (score -2):

None, as far as I know. They are usually not abbreviated.

個人情報 (personal information) is similar, 
but it includes the name of the person.

Comment: でも・・　チャットで「asl?」とか「asl plz」とか書きますけど「個人情報教えて」なんて書く人いませんし、仮にそう書いても「asl」を尋ねていることすら通じませんよね・・

Comment: interesting. so Japanese chat rooms use the English abbreviation.... are there any other things where the English way of asking is more popular than any Japanese way? I was looking at a lot of "Japanese chat expressions" after this question was asked.

Comment: @eric Oh, no we don't use "asl" in Japanese chat rooms... I meant to say in English chat rooms you use "asl?" "asl plz" but we don't use the term 個人情報 to ask "asl?" -- By the way, "asl" is almost outdated now, no? I haven't seen it used in chat for years..

Comment: ^ `Is there a term for ”ASL” when used in chats? ... Is there a similar term used in Japanese?`に対する答えは、`None` になると思いますね・・ たぶん誰に聞いても・・